# Reactive Extensions subscribing to an observable (subject)

Tags: task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I'm just playing around with Reactive Extensions for the first time in a winforms application. Mind you I have been doing web development for the past 4 years, and I am very familiar with observables and observable pattern in knockout, which I am guessing is contributing to my confusion here.

Anyhow, to the question and code. I have a simple winforms experiment (see below) that I was building to illustrate my question. The subscribe below doesn't run until well after the thread in start new is finished. I can trace it the calls to OnNext, but the subscribe doesn't fire at all until sometimes 20-30 seconds later. Can somebody explain this behavior to me?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Subject<int> progress;
    private CancellationToken cancellationToken;
    private IScheduler _scheduler;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationToken = source.Token;

        _scheduler = new SynchronizationContextScheduler(SynchronizationContext.Current);


    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progress
            .ObserveOn(_scheduler)
            //.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Subscribe(
                (i) => {
                    progressBar1.Do<ProgressBar>(ctl =>
                    {
                        ctl.Value = i;
                    });
                },
                (ex) => { },
            cancellationToken
        );

        Task counterTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                progress.OnNext(i);
            }
        }, cancellationToken,
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
      );
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       progress = new Subject<int>();
    }


}



public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Do<TControl>(this TControl control, Action<TControl> action)
      where TControl : Control
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
            control.Invoke(action, control);
        else
            action(control);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from the fact that your task is running on the UI thread, because you're using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`.

Hence your various `Sleep` calls are blocking the UI thread, freezing the UI (e.g. can't drag the window) and preventing your observable subscription to execute (because the `ObserveOn`, it's supposed to execute on the UI thread scheduler).

Replace `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` by `TaskScheduler.Default` (background TaskPool threads), and everything will work as you expected.

Note that your call to `Do`/`Invoke` is unnecessary, because you're already on the UI thread by the scheduler you've provided.

Comment: This is where I'm getting a bit lost. If I change the StartNew scheduler to TaskScheduler.Default then something weird happens. If I put a breakpoint at the OnNext and run it freezes the IDE, I get a the waiting cursor for few seconds then hit F11 and it just doesn't do anything from that point forward.

Comment: maybe clean/rebuild/restart VS ? I did the very same scenario and the IDE is fine. Try w/o debug/breakpoint also, and you should get your behavior.